# B2B App authentication on GAE - Google Accounts or custom user base (Django or Web2Py)?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, web2py

Which of these would you pick for a B2B app (targeting small/med-small businesses) built on GAE with python:

- Google Accounts
- Custom Users with Django
- Custom Users with Web2Py

I'm very tempted to go the Google Accounts route as it's very well integrated into GAE and takes care of everything from user creation to session authentication, and even takes care of forgotten passwords. However, I'm sure there are significant drawbacks to this, including usability, but if you are starting from scratch, which approach would you pick and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started with Google account, added all OpenID and quickly found that the only accounts people use for my site are google and facebook accounts. So now I only have login with google and login with facebook. But I'm going to add my own accounts and I'm doing it with webapp2 instead of django and instead of web2py. I tried web2py but webapp2 and its auth model seem much better and not like with web2py a lot of unnecessary code that is not for app engine.

Try this and its auth model (there is example code from http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/issues/detail?id=20) and I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I was wondering what that auth module did... thank you, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: The main reason to use web2py on appengine is that it allows you to write code that runs on appengine but also on regular vps hosting with sql database so you are not locked in. The web2py auth has lots of extra features like support for multiple single sign on services (including OpenID, Oauth and CAS, both provider and consumer). By default it deploys them all but you can deleted the modules that you do not use if space is a concern.

Comment: [webapp2 can also be run outside of App Engine](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html), however it will be missing a lot of the "batteries included" functionality in the GAE SDK that makes the framework so appealing.

Answer (score 2):

Google Accounts forces users to have Google Apps or Gmail accounts. Some customers might not like this.

Rolling your own is an (unnecessary) burden: you have to have sign up process (with captcha and/or 3rd party email confirmation), keep all user records, handle the security, etc..

I'd suggest you go with OpenID: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options

Comment: Thank you, I should have pointed this out in the question - I ruled out OpenID at the start as 99% of my users wouldn't know what OpenID is. I expect majority to have Google Account, as this idea overlaps with Google Places demographics (business owners).

Answer (score 1):

Why both Create Django user from Google users. you will be able to adapt your system user with other system next

Answer (score 1):

*I've understood that question was only on authentication after I've written this so most of things here are offtopic, but I just wanted to demotivate on using full-stack solutions like django or web2py in appengine.*

I can tell you something about django because I've used it for over a year and I do like it for certain types of websites. It was first framework which I've tried to use on appengine and I've dropped it after two weeks.

These are things in django which doesn't work or make no sense in appengine:

- **django models and orm**: designed for sql; appengine sdk has its own models.
- **django admin site**: is designed for sql databases, doesn't work on appengine
- **auto-forms from models**: designed for django models
- **django management commands**: none of commands which come with django is useful when working with appengine SDK.
- **django development server**: appengine sdk has its own development server, django's one does not work.
- **django "plugable apps" architecture**: at least in my practice it was useless on appengine.
- **static files collector**: great tool to collect static files from various reusable applications into one folder, only if you have many reusable applications.

There exists django-nonrel project which says it can run django with admin site on appengine. It can, with half of things working and a lot of bugs. You spend more time trying to fix what does not work than building things.

What might be useful from django framework:

- **django forms**: can be exchanged for a better library [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/dev/)
- **django url routing**: can use [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) instead
- **django request/response objects and HTTP exceptions**: can use Werkzeug instead
- **django pretty-printing exceptions**: Werkzeug does it better, it [adds a web debugger](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/#using-the-debugger).
- **django i18n and localization**: can be changed with [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/)
- **django templates**: [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) is similar and a lot faster, which is important because appengine is an expensive platform. `ctypes` module is required to debug errors in jinja templates, however `ctypes` is forbidden on appengine, but [on development server it does work](http://kay-docs.shehas.net/debugging.html?highlight=ctypes#exception-in-jinja2-template), for debugging you don't need more.

Actually Jinja2, Werkzeug, WTForms and babel are so cool, that there exists projects for each of them which integrates them with django.

I know two frameworks which use these libraries:

- [kay-framework](http://code.google.com/p/kay-framework/): made for appengine, a bit outdated, but a great example how you can use Jinja2, babel and Werkzeug on appengine.
- [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) from Armin Ronacher, the man behind Werkzeug and Jinja2.

I've not used web2py, however since it is also a full-stack framework like django is, I think it will be as bad as django is. ***Full-stack solutions simply do not fit in this  different environment. Simple libraries fit in any environment.***

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely informative and is a long the lines of what I was thinking as well. This is exactly why I don't even want to roll my own users, if I can help it.